# Inequality expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a nonnegative random variable and $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative constants. I am trying to prove that

$\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[((a-X+b)^+-X)^+] \leq \mathbb{E}[((a-X)^++b-X)^+],
\end{equation}$

where $x^+=\max(x,0)$. So far without any progress. Any thoughts?

Comment: Prove that $((a-x+b)^{+}-x)^{+}\leq ((a-x)^{+}+b-x)^{+}$ for all non-negative real numbers $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $b$ is nonnegative you have (by exhaustion)
$$(a-x+b)^+\leq(a-x)^+ +b$$
and since $x\mapsto\max(x,0)$ is a monotone increasing function you receive
$$((a-x+b)^+-x)^+\leq((a-x)^+ +b-x)^+.$$
Now you just have to use the monotonicity of the expected value. You see by this proof that the assumption "$a$ is nonnegative" is not requiered.

Comment: thanks for your clear answer. Indeed, nonnegativity of $a$ is not required.

Comment: technically shouldn't it be that $x\mapsto \text{max}(x,0)$ is an $\textit{increasing}$ monotone function?

Comment: Yes, I added it.